# how to Upload App folder's contain Backend and Frontend folder to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, nodes

I created an app called my-book(folder) and this has two folders called my-book-frontend and my-book-backend which are build to React and NodeJS.

Can anyone help to do, please because I could not understand the procedure how to upload my app folder which has my-book-frontend and my-book-backend.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in Internet a long time and I found a way to upload your App in Internet, you need have a account in Vercel.com (is free), and after in your Angular proyect folder write these commands:

1- ng build --prod //Generate the dist folder

2- npm install -g now //install the tool

3- now //in our directory "dist"

4- ?Set up and deploy -> Yes

5- Introduce our Vercel account

6- ?Link proyect -> No

7- Set proyect name //Enter, dont write nothing

8- ?Override settings -> Yes

9- Choose -> Build Command

And finally you will have a link what finish in .now.sh, oppen this link from any device in the internet explorer and you will have your app in internet.

PD: in vercel.com you could change DNS, etc. beacause if you have a domain, you could change your url (http:/.....now.sh) for what do you want.

This mhettod is tested in Angular 8 and 9 without problems.

This is my first post, i hope it could help many people.